# Simplest OpenCV program won't compile with error "empty attribute blocks not allowed"

Tags: c++, opencv

In Visual Studio 2008, I am attempting to run a basic OpenCV program I found on the internet.It is the supposed to be the simplest program while still working with OpenCV. I can post the source code if needed, but the error seems to pertain to the contents of the include files.
My three includes are:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
```

And the error generated when I compile is:

```
c:\users\noah huber-feely\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\opencvtests\opencvtests\targetver.h(10) : error C3409: empty attribute block is not allowed
```

The same error is generated for stdafx.h.

No other content on the web seems to have addressed this particular issue, so I am at a loss. If anyone could point me in the right direction or assist me in discovering the solution it would be much appreciated.

Here is the full source code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main ( int argc, char* arv[] )
{
    IplImage *image = 0;
    image = cvLoadImage("C:\Users\Noah Huber-Feely\Desktop\IMG_1484.jpg", 1);
    if( image )
    {
        cvNamedWindow( "Input Image", 1);
        cvShowImage( "Input Image", image);
        printf( "Press a key to exit\n");
        cvWaitKey(0);
        cvDestroyWindow( "String" );
    }
    else
        fprintf( stderr, "Error reading image\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the content of targetver.h:

```
#pragma once

// The following macros define the minimum required platform.  The minimum required platform
// is the earliest version of Windows, Internet Explorer etc. that has the necessary features to run 
// your application.  The macros work by enabling all features available on platform versions up to and 
// including the version specified.

// Modify the following defines if you have to target a platform prior to the ones specified below.
// Refer to MSDN for the latest info on corresponding values for different platforms.
[!if DLL_APP || WIN_APP || SUPPORT_MFC || SUPPORT_ATL]
#ifndef WINVER                          // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Windows Vista.
#define WINVER 0x0600           // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif

[!endif]
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT            // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Windows Vista.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600     // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of Windows.
#endif

[!if DLL_APP || WIN_APP || SUPPORT_MFC || SUPPORT_ATL]
#ifndef _WIN32_WINDOWS          // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Windows 98.
#define _WIN32_WINDOWS 0x0410 // Change this to the appropriate value to target Windows Me or later.
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE                       // Specifies that the minimum required platform is Internet Explorer 7.0.
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0700        // Change this to the appropriate value to target other versions of IE.
#endif
[!endif]
```

Comment: addition of source code will be appreciated

Comment: Post your code, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: What's in "targetver.h", esp. targetver.h-Line 10?

Comment: "attempting to run a basic OpenCV program I found on the internet." - OOOUUCH ! please throw that away at once and try something from here instead. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html